# WSO2 IS(pre-packaged) as Key Manager to API-M error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

The pre-packaged Identity Server cannot mount  _system/config as specified in registry.xml:

```
<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

After configuring and initial start-up (sh wso2server -Dsetup) I get:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Unable to create fixed remote mounts. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance
```

Then I configured API-M , started up , successfully creates both mounts.

Restarted IS and get :

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Connected to mount at govregistry in 2ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService}
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Unable to create fixed remote mounts. {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: An exception occurred while executing handler chain. null
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.delete(HandlerManager.java:2649)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.delete(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:215)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.delete(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:452)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.delete(EmbeddedRegistry.java:843)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.delete(CacheBackedRegistry.java:512)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.deleteInternal(UserRegistry.java:870)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1100(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:845)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$12.run(UserRegistry.java:842)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.delete(UserRegistry.java:842)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.setupMounts(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:343)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:572)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:70)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.delete(MountHandler.java:492)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.delete(HandlerManager.java:2627)
    ... 50 more
```

The registry view in IS console shows that governance is successfully mounted.

Should the IS config registry be shared/mounted? If so please advise or update the documentation.

Also is this correct in registry.xml as per the doc ?:

```
<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">    
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
```

Should that be my local IP address and also the db previously created is registry not registrydb

is/repository/conf/registry.xml

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">

        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>

    </dbConfig>


    <dbConfig name="govregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">    
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

API-M/repository/conf/registry.xml :

```
 <dbConfig name="wso2registry">

        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>

    </dbConfig>

<dbConfig name="govregistry">
       <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">    
       <id>gov</id>
       <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
       <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
       <readOnly>false</readOnly>
       <enableCache>true</enableCache>
       <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

I have followed (https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.0)

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is problem with mount governance space.
Governance space in Identity Server has already been mounted after define the  from mentioned IdS as KeyManager guide.

The config space isn`t configured correctly, because in registry.xml the 'conf' mount is after the 'governance'. 
When 'conf' part will be moved before 'governance' the error will stil appear, but 'config' will appear as remote space in registry browser in wso2 web console.

Below is mentioned registry.xml mounting order:

```
<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
   <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
   <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issues with reistry configuration. Please make sure your registry.xml configurations are correct. Please clean the database and restart the both servers.

IS Side:

```
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">    
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

APIM Side :

```
<dbConfig name="govregistry">
       <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

<remoteInstance url="https://localhost">    
       <id>gov</id>
       <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
       <cacheId>root@jdbc:mysql://10.20.30.42:3306/registrydb</cacheId>
       <readOnly>false</readOnly>
       <enableCache>true</enableCache>
       <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>

<mount path="/_system/config" overwrite="true">
       <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
       <targetPath>/_system/config</targetPath>
</mount>
```

Comment: Have verified the registry files. I have followed the documentation exactly.  See above edit for configs. Still do not understand why the remoteInstance cacheId is pointing to a database that does not exist (registrydb) and some funny IP address 10.20.30.42 ... When I change that to 'apiuser@jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registry'  , the same error occurs however the IS successfully connects to both mounts...

Comment: Managed to solve the issues when also replacing the H2 db with a MySql db(for IS and AM) , if any one needs help with this config , e-mail me